# 受信箱の「ようこそ」をクリックすると「ツアー」に飛ばずにプロフィール編集に飛ぶ

Tags: バグ, 再現性なし

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. It should be taking you to the `/tour` page.

Comment: It goes to `/tour` now... whether or not it did back in October is a good question. :)